# take (something) off

Tags: grammaticality

Can someone please guide me if it should be  'take your email off' or 'take you off'

I’ve also requested John to take your email off the notifications we receive from the HR team.

OR

I’ve also requested John to take you off the notifications we receive from the HR team.

Thanks

Comment: In my version of English, it’s not possible to "request" someone to do something; you can use "ask" that way but not "request". In my dialect you have to "request that someone do something", which is stuffy sounding.

Comment: I've also asked John to remove you from the email notification list that the HR team uses.

Answer (score 0):

For this context, I'd suggest "Remove" or "Unsubscribe"

> I've requested that John **remove** your/his/her email address from the HR Team notifications emails

or

> I've requested that John **unsubscribe** you/his/her email address from the HR team notification mailing list

Comment: Hi Pete, John is the person whom I have requested this to make this change.

Comment: @Tanu  My apologies.  I've edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: "you/him/her email address" is a typo, surely?

Comment: @TonyK - Obviously, yes.

Comment: That's better! You're almost there...